# Crop image into circle shape using REACT.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

Currently working on my portfolio. I used [this](https://github.com/cobiwave/simplefolio) template. I'm trying to make my profile image into a circle shape. I can't figure out where I would put borderRadius or border-radius. Here's what it currently looks like https://sarairamadanportfolio.netlify.app/

Here's the source code: https://github.com/sramadan7/professionalportfolio/tree/gh-pages/src
I tried adding borderRadius and border-radius under the img tag on the index.html page but no change. Then, I tried to add both of these to _about.scss and still no change. Not sure where else to put it so that the image is a circle shape instead of rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't work but when you want to add style in react jsx elements, you need to use the camelCase style for it: <div style={{borderRadius: '50%'}}>. When you want to add style in css, you would space the word out using -: border-radius: 50%;

Comment: I just fixed the post to have the updated link. Would I put <div style={{borderRadius: '50%'}}> in the _about.scss file then?

Comment: It'll be much better to show what part of the code you need to work with instead of sending the repo but theoretically, that wouldn't work because html elements don't work in sass files. If you have no specificity issues, then just adding border-radius: 50%; should work. Make sure the class or id you have is on the img tag and not accidentally on another element.